# Is ASP.NET MVC supposed to be this slow in a shared environment?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, shared-hosting

This is probably going to be quite an extensive post. But i've done my research and now i'm stuck, and I really wan't to get to the bottom of this.

The problem i'm having is the performance of a ASP.NET MVC 3 site in a shared environment (web host). If you look at the following graph you'll see what I mean:
[Loading time graph from KeepAliveForever](http://mikaeledebro.se/misc/screenshot.png)

As you can see, the site has these peaks where the loading time is around 10 secs every 20-30 minutes, and that is's loading normally between this. Since it's a shared host they recycle the application pools every 20 minutes.
Although I was under the impression that only sites without activity would be "thrown out" from the cache. Since the service KeepAliveForever are supposed to request the site every 10 minutes, this doesn't seem to be the case for me. No matter what happens, the site seems to be dropped from the cache.

This is the command I use to precompile the site:

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
aspnet_compiler -p "c:\dev\AlltForMusik\AlltForMusik" -v / -f "c:\dev\Deploy"
```

I've also disabled debugging and commented out the RegisterAllAreas() in Global.asax, since I don't use areas and i've read that it can be quite slow:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //Database.SetInitializer(new DontDropDbJustCreateTablesIfModelChanged<AlltForMusikContext>());

        //AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

I have maybe 15 routes added to the RegisterRoutes() in Global.asax. But this is quite a normal amount right, and shouldn't be causing any significant delays?

The site is pretty lightweight and the only things that are loaded from the DB can be seen here: [Components from the DB](http://mikaeledebro.se/misc/fromDb.png)

I've read that this is a problem for many others, but I can't fathom that this is supposed to be the expected result. I mean, most smaller sites use shared hosting environments with load balancing. How am I going to be able to use MVC to develop sites for customers if the sites are going to be this slow?! This will never be tolerated by a paying client!

Or is MVC really only supposed to be used when building large scale apps that's running on it's own server (with the ability to change prefs etc)?

Really appreciate your time and effort to help me solve this. I've spoken to my web host and they can't really help. The web host is not overall slow, this only seem to be a problem for MVC sites.

Best regards
Mikael Edebro

Comment: Where are the images coming from?

Comment: They are located on the server. The path to the image is stored in a simple db table. I'm not storing the image itself in a db. The images are really small (the ones in the main column like 3-4 kb), so I doubt this is the problem. And they ought to be in the browser cache already.

Comment: I'm going to bookmark this question because I have the same problems with my web host too...If I deploy an MVC site, it's dog slow compared to the webforms application. Who's your hosting provider?

Comment: Im using a host called City Network here in Sweden. But I ran the site on a similar host before and I had the same problem. I think the issue is more related to MVC on a shared host, rather than a specific hosting provider. Almost all of them have the same practices in place.

Comment: I developed sites in Classic ASP about 10 years ago that had really sloppy code, but that was still outperforming this one. I find it strange that the people at Microsoft havn't put more effort into explaining about this, and to find possible solutions. I don't feel it should be needed to "tweak the shit out of the site" just to get loading times under 10 secs?!

Comment: It was all about the web host. I just moved the site to winhost.com and now everything is flowing nicely with response times under 1 sec. I definitly recommend them, or at least to try some web host that specializes in Windows hosting.